# how can i get all the hyperlinks and its paragraphs in an website?

Tags: java, web-scraping, web-crawler, jsoup, urlconnection

I want to get all hyperlinks and name it as .txt file, and i want to store all paragraphs inside those each hyperlinks and save as a text file by their article title.

i have the code here and i am fixing this for 2 months. i could not get code for this crawling/scraping logic.
Anyone please code and fix it.

```
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
   import java.io.Reader;
   import java.net.URI;
   import java.net.URISyntaxException;
    import java.net.URL;
     import java.net.URLConnection;

      import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
     import javax.swing.text.EditorKit;
     import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
   import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

     import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
      import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
     import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

     public class App {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException,
        IOException, BadLocationException {
    HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument() {
        public HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback getReader(int pos) {
            return new HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback() {
                public void handleText(char[] data, int pos) {
                    System.out.println(data);
                }
            };
        }
    };

    URL url = new URI("http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org/").toURL();
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    Reader rd = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("ram.txt"), "UTF-8");

    EditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    kit.read(rd, doc, 0);
    try {
        Document docs = Jsoup.connect(
                "http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org/").get();

        Elements links = docs.select("a[href]");

        Elements elements = docs.select("*");
        System.out.println("Total Links :" + links.size());

        for (Element element : elements) {
            System.out.println(element.ownText());
        }
        for (Element link : links) {
            String hrefUrl = link.attr("href");
            if (!"#".equals(hrefUrl) && !hrefUrl.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(" * a: link :" + hrefUrl);
                System.out.println(" * a: text :" + link.text());
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(hrefUrl)
                        .timeout(0) //Infinite timeout
                        .get();
                String html = document.toString();
                writer.write(html);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want ro get all article content from all links inside from an website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014436/i-want-ro-get-all-article-content-from-all-links-inside-from-an-website)

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34103917/1992780).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class NewClass {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


      Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org").get();
      Elements section = doc.select("section#content");
      Elements article = section.select("article");
      for (Element a : article) {
        System.out.println("Title : \n" + a.select("a").text());
        System.out.println("Article summary: \n" + a.select("div.entry-summary").text());
      }
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you include a short explanation of what you are doing?

Comment: My english is not good but i'll try to tell what i did. 
1. Jsoup.connect("url") connect to the page
2. select("cssQuery") select from the page those parts in which you are interested. For example select("h2") will return all h2 elements of the page; select ("h2#someId") returns one h2 element with the id = someId

Comment: and select("div.entry-summary") returns all divs in the class entry-summary

Comment: @MrHug : Its called web Crawling/scraping which I am writing code by using url connector in java. i want to extract the contents from the website using jsoup in java. Like all we can extract <div class> <p> and all hyperlink <a>. Finally after extracting I am saving it in an text document.

Comment: @user5664421: thanks i want this type of code.But it is getting the title and contents of the hyperlinks from the main page.I want to use some iterator and to get all articles from which the homepage links are redirecting to other hyperlinks. Its like Breadth First Search Algorithm.

Comment: [link[ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) Exactly this iteration @user5664421 please look on this.

Comment: @RamKi, I know that, but the OP might not. Thus some explanation for him is why I requested it ;)